# Grouping Adjacent date-times in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a requirement that, I need to group the date-time which are close to each other. like the gap between each group is 30 min. and need to get the min, max and time difference (b/w MIN and MAX times).

My scenario is I have a log transaction-table. Each time user make any request it is capturing. And I want to find how long each user spend on my application. For that I need to group the times which are closer so  can find min and max of time further for calculating duration.

I'm not familiar with deep SQL concepts. Any idea to achieve this?

| message_time | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-14 10:07:49.358739 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 10:08:16.156553 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 10:08:32.195645 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 13:36:16.103253 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:46:43.871769 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:50:42.867178 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:55:30.530697 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:56:42.472823 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:57:05.880580 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:57:40.377021 | 4 |
| 2020-12-14 13:58:12.723215 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 14:34:30.633401 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:16:18.188387 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:16:30.735493 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:18:03.501372 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:50:46.953427 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:51:11.772787 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:59:34.264237 | 11 |
| 2020-12-15 13:02:10.622184 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 10:28:27.489880 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 10:28:43.793308 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 19:29:56.208375 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 19:45:34.401379 | 12 |

Answer (score 0):

You can define Time table, with 30 minutes in each group

- TimeReference

  - StartTime - Time datatype
  - EndTime - Time datatype
  - GroupNumber - TINYINT datatype

| StartTime | EndTime | GroupNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 00:30:00 | 1 |
| 00:30:00 | 01:00:00 | 2 |

Now, you need to filter on a date and take only time portion and see which group the login time belong to. pseudo code is given below:

```sql
SELECT l.user, t.GroupNumber
FROM log_transaction_table as l
inner join TimeReference as t
on CONVERT(TIME, l.starttime) > t.StartTime
AND convert(TIME, l.endtime) <= t.Endtime
WHERE l.datevaluefilter >= '2020-03-12' l.datevaluefilter < '2020-03-13'
```